# Find the limit of $ a_n=\sqrt[n]{ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right) },~\text{where}~f(x)=1-\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=1-\sin x$ for $x \in \Bbb R$. Define
$$
a_n=\sqrt[n]{ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right) },
$$
Then, which of the following is/are correct?

(a) $\left\{a_n\right\}_n$ converges to $0$

(b) $\left\{a_n\right\}_n$ diverges to $\infty$

(c) $\left\{a_n\right\}_n$ converges and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n>0$

(d) none of the other three options is correct

I tried to find an estimate as arithmetic mean,
$$a_n \leq \frac{n+\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+...+\sin\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)}{n},$$
But, how to find the limit even though $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Take logarithm. You wil get a limit of Riemann sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By taking logarithms on both sides we get:
$\log a_n=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{\log f\left( \dfrac{i}{n} \right)}}{n}$. We set the partition $\mathfrak{Z} =\left( 0,\dfrac{1}{n},\cdots ,\dfrac{n}{n}=1 \right) =\left( \alpha _0,\alpha _1,\cdots ,\alpha _n \right)$, and therefore we have using the Riemann sum:

$$\,\,\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n{\log f\left( \dfrac{i}{n} \right)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{\left( \alpha _i-\alpha _{i-1} \right) \cdot \log f\left( \alpha _i \right)}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1{\log f\left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x}=\int_0^1{\log \left( 1-\sin x \right) \mathrm{d}x}$$

The expression is quite complicated, but from the graph (or through some basic analysis, i.e. continuity & boundedness) we can see that the integral is some concrete negative number $x$:

[image]

thus taking the exponential again we have:
$$a_n \to \exp(\log a_n)=\exp(x)\approx 0.478>0 (n\to \infty)$$

Therefore (c) is correct.